# Redirecting stdout from function running in a QThread?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to make console widget, and my current step in this process is getting a function that calls `input()` multiple times, to redirect to a `QTextEdit` widget.

My current implementation works just fine with non-interactive functions, like `print()`, but it doesn't work with interactive ones, like `input()`. It doesn't print the input prompt in my terminal, or set the text of `QTextEdit`. I have the function setup so it's running through a `QThread`, so I have no idea why it isn't working.

Here's the implementation of my terminal widget:

```
from contextlib import redirect_stdout
from io import StringIO

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTextEdit
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, QThread, pyqtSignal

class Terminal(QTextEdit):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(Terminal, self).__init__(parent)

    def run_func(self, func, *args, **kwargs):
        self.thread = QThread()
        self.worker = TerminalWorker(func, args, kwargs)
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)
        self.thread.started.connect(self.worker.run)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.thread.quit)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.worker.deleteLater)
        self.thread.finished.connect(self.thread.deleteLater)
        self.worker.outputChanged.connect(self.update_terminal)
        self.thread.start()

    def update_terminal(self, text):
        print(text)
        self.setText(text)


class TerminalWorker(QObject):
    finished = pyqtSignal()
    outputChanged = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, func, args, kwargs):
        QObject.__init__(self)
        self.func = func
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def run(self):
        with redirect_stdout(StringIO()) as f:
            self.func(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
            print(f)
        self.outputChanged.emit(f.getvalue())
```

[Here's the rest of my source code](https://github.com/lumbo7332/qt-terminal).

Comment: One obvious problem is that result of `input()` goes to stdin, not stdout. But that's not the only potential problem you face, as shown in [this article](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2015/redirecting-all-kinds-of-stdout-in-python/) and [this bug report](https://bugs.python.org/issue1927).

Comment: Yeah. I decided that QThread wasn't worth it. So I ended up using `multiprocessing` and `threading`. https://gitlab.com/lumbo7332/portmod/-/tree/gui/portmod/_gui